# Creating a Bayesian Average for each Product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use the following formula to calculate a Bayesian score for each of my products, based on their scores (0-100) and number of votes:

> ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) /
>   (avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)

Each product has_many reviews, and each review has a 'score' which is 0-100.

When pulling the list of products from the database what would be the best approach to calculating the Bayesian score to be listed in a table in the view?

EDIT: I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
Product.each do |product|
  @product_bayesian = ((Review.count * Review.average(:score)) + (product.reviews.count + product.reviews.average(:score))/(Review.count+product.reviews.count)
end
```

but, done in the most efficient way possible, possibly through a join in the controller?

Comment: When you say votes, would each review equate to a vote?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of clarification... Review.count would = number of votes

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
    def overall
    @products = Product.all
    @overall_count = Review.count
    @overall_average = Review.average(:score)
    @unranked = {}

    @products.each do |product| 
      @review_score_raw = product.reviews.average(:score) 
      @review_score = @review_score_raw.to_int if @review_score_raw 
      @review_count = product.reviews.count

      if product.reviews.count == 0 
        @bayesian = 0
      else 
          @bayesian = (((@overall_count * @overall_average) + (@review_count * @review_score_raw))/(@overall_count + @review_count)) 
      end 

      @unranked[product] = @bayesian
    end

    @ranked = @unranked.sort_by {|key, value| value}.reverse.each_with_index.to_a
end
```